# isolated tests, stub_const and modules

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a class that I want to spec. The class includes a module that I do not want to load. Application code goes something like this:

```
class Foo
  include Bar
  ...
end
```

In my isolated spec, I only require `foo.rb`, but upon doing that, Ruby attempts to include the `Bar` module constant, which at this point has not been defined.

Rspec offers a method called `stub_const`, but it appears to be intended for use inside examples, so the constant can be undefined again upon the clean up after the example.

This will obviously not work if `stub_const` is called outside of an example.

What is the optimal way to solve this problem? The solution should ideally

- allow Rspec to load my class
- define a fake module of my choosing
- run examples which instantiate the Foo class that now includes the fake module
- undefine the fake module to return the original state

Answer (score 0):

What about defining an empty (or stubbed) Bar module beforehand?

With foo.rb:

```
class Foo
  include Bar

  def to_s
    "Foo"
  end
end
```

This foo_test.rb does works:

```
module Bar
end

require 'foo'

f = Foo.new
```

The empty module needs to appear before the require of foo, but you could set it up in a specific file in your test suite (especially if you have to reuse it).

Comment: This is doable, but not ideal, as it litters the Ruby rspec process with an empty `Bar` module in subsequent specs. Also, `Bar` may have been defined in a previous spec and contain methods that allow the `Foo` spec to pass, when it should rightfully have failed or vice versa.

In other words, this does not create fully isolated tests.